# Remove text after last full stop " . "

Tags: php

i want to remove all the text after the last occurring of " . " in a given paragraph.

For example from this paragraph i want to remove all text after last full stop.

> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Rich

Length of the paragraph is dynamic only thing to be removed is text after last " . "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`strrpos`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) and [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$pos = strrpos($paragraph, '.');
$withOutDot = substr($paragraph, 0, $pos). '.';
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfect... Is there a way to remove the text and keep the last full stop ???

Comment: @HarjeetSingh If it resolved your prolem, why not accept this answer? :) `$withOutDot` contains paragraph with last full stop. And what do ou mean by remove text? Append parsed text to `$paragraph`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
new_string = substr(old_string, 0, strchr(old_string, '.'));
```

`strchr` finds the position of the last occurrence of '.' in `old_string`. `substr` returns a new string consisting of the characters in `old_string` between positions 0 and the position found by `strchr`.

- http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
- http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php

Comment: To keep the full stop, just change the second argument to: `strchr(old_string, '.') + 1`

Comment: this isn't right. `strchr` finds the *first* occurence, `strrchr` finds the *last* occurence

Answer (score 0):

For me, the above solutions didn't work out so finally i got some code by myself so it may help to other people.

```
<?php 
    $trim_content = "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Rich";
    $place = strripos($trim_content,".");
    $content = substr($trim_content,$place);
    echo str_replace($content,".",$trim_content);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with explode.

$summary = explode(".",$summary);

$summary=$summary[1]

here you will get text till the first full stop